# Timestamps for the committed offsets in Kafka through the admin API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In kafka, the committed offsets for a certain consumer group can be requested through the admin client API using a code similar to the below:

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets =
        admin.listConsumerGroupOffsets(CONSUMER_GROUP)
                .partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();
```

Suppose that that `log.message.timestamp.type` is set to `LogAppendTime`

When committing offsets by a consumer to the __consumer_offsets topic, any timestamp is written implicitly along with the committed offsets? Can this timestamp be retrieved using kafka Admin client API? Any other method to get such timestamp if any?

Thank you.

Comment: The timestamp is part of the ConsumerRecord. Why do you need it from the AdminClient?

Comment: I have an independent monitoring process in the cluster that is requesting latest and committed offsets through the admin APIs (hence, no access to the consumer APIs etc..), I can get the timestamp associated with the latest offset, but looking for a method to get the timestamp associated with the last committed offset if any? suggestions?